# attrs not resolved or not a field

Tags: android, button, attr

As with many I am writing my first app. I am trying to use the three button toggle from here: http://androidasilearnit.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/custom-toggle-button/

The only problem I have at the moment is I have created the attrs.xml file and it is in the res/values folder. However, when I have created the TriToggleButton.java class I am getting errors on all three states that are declared in attrs.xml

```
//Get the attributes created in attrs.xml
private static final int[] STATE_ONE_SET =
{
    R.attr.state_one
};

private static final int[] STATE_TWO_SET =
{
    R.attr.state_two
};

private static final int[] STATE_THREE_SET =
{
    R.attr.state_three
};
```

I have looked in R.java (as that was a suggested fix) and they are not in there. I can see all the other XML info in there but not the attr

Any ideas?

Edit:
Here is the attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomButtonState">
        <!-- Use one for every state you want to have  -->
        <attr name="litres" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="usgal" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="impgal" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Oh and the clean has really broken it. Now all my resources are not being found!! IN MainActivity.java I am now getting "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Mind posting your attrs.xml section? Try doing a Project > Clean, that helps resolve most R.java related issues.

Comment: Also, what errors are you getting? Most of the time you may get funny errors when the XML file is not syntax-correct. This also is a large cause of R.java not generating correctly.

Comment: did you imported `android.R` in your class ? if so remove it and import your class Resources

Comment: OK I just looked and android.R had been added to the imports in MainActivity.java, I have removed that but all my resources are still unresolved. Can you just explain exactly what you mean by "import your class resources"

Comment: OK after much panicing I found a suggestion to create a dummy XML and delete it and this has me back to the stage I was at the start. All my errors are gone EXCEPT R.java is still not updating. If I comment out any errors the compile fails with this error: Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Users\Graham's\Documents\Android\workspace\FuelCheck\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those in the future. Whenever I have this problem it is invariably an XML problem. For me, it is generally always the menu. As far as i can tell it is an eclipse problem because I can delete the whole XML and the R.java will update. I can post the whole XML back in unchanged and the program will compile and run without problem. It is tedious but I can work around it.